# DuplicateKeyException wile bean creation Spring-data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a POJO ( `ExcursionAttendee` ) annotation with `@Document(collection = "excursionAttendees")` annotation and there is a repository class without any custom methods.

```
public interface ExcursionAttendeeRepository extends MongoRepository<ExcursionAttendee, String>
```

spring-data-mongodb is on 1.7.0.RELEASE and using mongo-java-driver 3.0.0 against mongodb 3.0 . When application is deploying following exception get thrown.

```
Error creating bean with name 'excursionAttendeeRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.DuplicateKeyException: Write failed with error code 11000 and error message 'null'
```

I have been searching in the internet and just couldn't figure out any reason for this. This is bean creation stage and it is not trying to do any update or upsert to cause any problems with indexes. What would be the issue here?

Below is full stack trace

```
06:33:08,212 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#0.1': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#604bbd0c' of type [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter] while setting bean property 'messageListener'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#604bbd0c': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'productDetailsEventConsumer' while setting bean property 'delegate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productDetailsEventConsumer': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cinglevue.veip.service.excursion.ExcursionAttendeeService com.cinglevue.veip.service.erp.impl.ProductDetailsEventConsumer.excursionAttendeeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'excursionAttendeeServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cinglevue.veip.repository.excursion.ExcursionAttendeeRepository com.cinglevue.veip.service.excursion.impl.ExcursionAttendeeServiceImpl.excursionAttendeeRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'excursionAttendeeRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.DuplicateKeyException: Write failed with error code 11000 and error message 'null'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1220) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762) [spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434) [spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SpringContextLoaderListener.java:44) [resteasy-spring-2.3.3.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3780) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

Comment: Do you have any newly added unique index in Document?

Comment: Can we see the full stacktrace?

Comment: @titogeo No. Only id index is there.

Comment: @GergelyBacso Yes sure. I added it to the question

Comment: Uhhh. It is really strange. Just for debugging purposes I would raise the loglevel of your app to TRACE to see more info about what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading mongo java driver it gave me enough evidence to find the issue.

```
Write failed with error code 11000 and error message 'exception: E11000 duplicate key error index: veip.guardians.$school._id dup key: { : null }'
```

There was a `@Index` annotation in a embedded object

```
@Id
@Indexed(unique=true)
private String id;
```

But in the data base this id property of embedded object is null for all documents. Which explain the exception.